# PHP / MySQL database daily reset

Tags: mysql, database, reset

I have a database on phpMyAdmin and I want to reset certain columns to the default value (`0`) every day at 7:00PM automatically.

Can any one help?

Comment: You need to write a php file in which add if condition and check if time is exactly 07:00 PM then execute that update query. Add this file in crone with 1 hour difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a cron job that executes an sql script in which you specify the sql code that resets the columns in question.